# Gorm retrieving query execution time

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to retrieve execution time of a query, say insertion, from gorm in Golang. I can see the time in miliseconds in the logs but I want a way to use that in my code, perhaps send this to an external monitoring system.

I read the documentation on using context in gorm. It was mostly concerned with providing gorm with timeout. I also did a lot of googling but found no matters on the subject. There were a lot of issues on github on SLOW sql logs but nothing that provided a way to retrieve execution time in code.

Answer (score 0):

*send this to an external monitoring system* ~ you want to **log** to another system and not default stdout.

This is a use case for [custom logger](https://gorm.io/docs/logger.html#Customize-Logger) in gorm.

Create a logger struct which implements `logger.Interface`. The one for your use is

`Trace(ctx context.Context, begin time.Time, fc func() (sql string, rowsAffected int64), err error)`

Time spent can be found by `time.Since(begin)`

**Note**: Do check how gorm default logger handles other parameters like `fc` and `err` for complete functionality.

Comment: I checked the default logger. and I don't think it's accurate. It computes the elapsed time by time.Since(begin). Let's say I have multiple goroutines and the goroutine logging yields the CPU so that another one can use it. Not only does the final elapsed time includes the query execution time, but also the time the goroutine wasn't allocated CPU time. This final result is more like turnaround time rather than execution time. How is this any different than doing `begin := time.Now() ; db.Create(&object) ; time.Since(begin)`, which doesn't involve the logger ?

Comment: Logger Trace func is called by gorm while executing the sql e.g. in [callbacks](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/master/callbacks.go#L134) where it gets the current time and calls `Trace` which calculates the time. Similarly in other places like [migrator](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/master/migrator/migrator.go#L37). So you will not directly call `Trace`, gorm will while executing the sql, there multiple goroutines will not impact the time.

Comment: _How is this any different than doing `begin := time.Now() db.Create(&object) time.Since(begin)`_  here you are calculating entire time used by `Create`, while with using logger, `Trace` is called at the point of executing the query.

Comment: I can't see why that solves problems that might arise with multiple goroutines