# How to get DB connection establishment statistics in GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

**Context:**

I am using [database/sql](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql) to maintain a pool of open connections. The configuration I'm using is as follows: maxIdleConnections = 20, maxOpenConnections = 100.

**Issue:**

During high traffic, all the idle connections are used up and any new API call is trying to create a new DB connection. And sometimes the DB connection is taking too long to establish, because of which the caller is timing out and cancelling the API call. This results in the query being cancelled and dial error being thrown.

**Question:**

Now, to debug further I want to understand which connection stage is taking up time e.g. DNS resolution, TLS handshake etc. Is there a way to get this breakdown in GORM?

In essence, is there a way to get something similar to TraceInfo in resty: https://github.com/go-resty/resty/blob/v2.8.0/request.go#L798?

Comment: How about using `DBStats`? https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.Stats

Comment: Or using `Logger` occurred to me like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76628021/gorm-retrieving-query-execution-time